# Colorbox with bxslider not working

Tags: jquery, colorbox, bxslider

Hello I am trying to use bxslider with colorbox. My implementation of bxslider is like an example listed **[here](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1)**. The difference is that I want only the pagers to be shown. Also when the user clicks one pager I want colorbox to open and have next and previous buttons. The problem is that I cant group the images with colorbox and next and previous button is not shown! The following code uses the rel option but with this way colorbox doesnt event start.

What I have tried till now is:

HTML

```
 <div class="slider_mini" style="position:relative;bottom:0px;">
    <div id="bx-pager">
       <a data-slide-index="0" href="image.jpg" class="imgz"><img style="width:130px;height:104px;" src="image.jpg"/></a>
       <a data-slide-index="1" href="image2.jpg" class="imgz"><img style="width:130px;height:104px;" src="image2.jpg"/></a>
       <a data-slide-index="2" href="image3.jpg" class="imgz"><img style="width:130px;height:104px;" src="image3.jpg"/></a>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.imgz').colorbox({rel:'imgz'});

            $('.bxslider.two').bxSlider({
                pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
            });

            $('#bx-pager').bxSlider({
                slideWidth: 130,
                minSlides: 2,
                maxSlides: 3,
                moveSlides: 1,
                slideMargin: 10
            });




        });
</script>
```

Not working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n53nN/).

**Feedback**: The problem was in live website that I was calling colorbox before bxslider. I put the call after bxslider's and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be because you have missed the `rel` attribute in anchors:

```
<a data-slide-index="0" href="image.jpg" rel="imgz" class="imgz">
     <!---------------add the rel here---^^^^^^^^^------>
    <img style="width:130px;height:104px;" src="image.jpg"/>
</a>
```

### [Your fiddle in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/n53nN/2/)

Comment: Yes I think it works with classes too. I think I have tried it with rel too, let me try again and I will let you know. Edit: It does not work either.

Comment: @BillK, may be stupid question but are you including the scripts as in your fiddle you didn't bother and Jai's fiddle seems to work as you want it to

Comment: @Pete Sorry Pete I didnt know how to include them and I was searching right now in google how to do that

Comment: @Jai I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rel' of undefined , I wish I could post the online link.

Comment: Sounds like not all your elements with a class of `imgz` has a rel of `imgz` too.  and fiddle thing is left hand side external resources,  enter the url and click the plus sign

Comment: @BillK you can update to this: `$('.imgz').colorbox();` this would also work if your library is loaded properly.

Comment: I put the call for colorbox at the end of he script file after the call of bxslider and it worked. Thank you both guys. @Jai